# How to determine if a .NET DLL is an interop assembly?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, com-interop

I am converting an existing project to use nuget for packages dependencies. One part of this is building nuget packages that correctly set the reference properties if the assembly is an interop assembly (i.e., set EmbedInteropTypes to false). The problem is that there are a lot of assemblies that aren't clearly either a regular .NET assembly or an interop assembly. Is there some way to determine, purely from the assembly, if it is an interop assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was imported from a COM typelib, then the assembly should be marked with the [ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.importedfromtypelibattribute.aspx), as displayed here with the output from [ILDASM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help - this makes perfect sense.